# many click survey with jquery

Tags: jquery, click

To survey many clicks divs on documents (+100) and make specific actions if click, what is the best way ?

1)

```
$(document).on('click','body *',function(){
  var clique=$(this).attr('id');
  if(clique=="id1"){
    ...
  }
  if(clique=="id2"){
    ...
  }
  if ...
});
```

2)

```
$('body').on('click','#id1', function() { 
  ...
});
$('body').on('click','#id2', function() { 
  ...
});
...
```

3)

```
$('#id1').on('click', function() {
...
});
$('#id2').on('click', function() { 
...
});
...
```

4) ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A single event bonded to a class

```
$('body').on('click','.class',function() { 
...
});
```

Comment: ok, Thank you. this solution don't work after ajax. (div bulding by ajax)